# Fender hot rod deluxe connected to speaker simulator diagram

Tags: amplifiers, speakers

I am trying to connect my Fender hot rod deluxe tube amp to a speaker simulator. My speaker simulator is the Iron Cab which has a "link out", and the manual description says:

> Attention! When using IRon Cab with a guitar amp, be sure that the guitar cabinet/load emulation is connected to the LINK jack. Otherwise IRon Cab and the amp will be damaged.

I know I can go from speaker out to cab sim and then from LINK back to speaker, but I am wondering if I do the following connections without using the link, but the speaker is connected to my amp, am I damaging my amp?

[image: connection diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration in the diagram is **not** safe for your amp. **All** speaker jacks used on a tube amp must be connected to an appropriate load or the amp may be damaged from over-current.

You can either connect a single jack to a load (speaker or load box) and leave the external jack unused, or you can connect both the normal and external speaker jacks to two separate loads, but you can't connect one jack to a load and then connect the other jack to something that does not present the appropriate load.